# Stuck at boot logo due to removal of all nvidia drivers in deepin 15.6. What to do?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, deepin

I mistakenly removed all of my NVidia drivers in my Deepin 15.6. Actually, I was trying to fix my drivers but this happened. After which, I restarted my laptop, but I'm unable to boot into the desktop environment. The screen shows only the Deepin logo after filling up and then nothing works.

Also, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> does nothing, i.e. terminal is also not opening up. I used this command, for removal of drivers :

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

I am able to open both the recovery modes, one which is grub and one which is inside advanced options, But, nothing helpful seems to be there.

How can I solve this issue, as all my data is there in linux and it is very well setup with all my required packages?

Comment: @slm Edited the question.

Comment: In recovery mode if you can get to a command prompt with networking you can simply install via `apt-get`.  If you need to google, etc. then use a text based browser like `lynx`,`links`,`links2`, or `elinks`.  If you need to copy/paste, install and use `gpm`.

Comment: @gpm Thanks. But, the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booted into single mode by using this method -

1. Goto ‘*advanced options*’ for Deepin.
2. Press ‘*e*’ on the first kernel entry.
3. Find the line ending with ‘*ro quiet splash*’ and add ‘*single*’ after that with a space.
4. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to boot into *single* mode.
5. Install / Open **Deepin Graphics Driver Manager** and Select *NVidia* in that.
6. Reboot and again boot back to *single* mode.
7. Follow on-screen instructions to successfully install the drivers.
8. Now, you’ll be able to boot normally to your Deepin desktop.

But, Now installed *Ubuntu 18.04*, deleting Deepin after taking all the needed stuff.

Comment: Good to hear! :)